# Why is this c++ file program not overwriting the all previous content of the file?

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    fstream file;
    string data;

    file.open("newFile.txt", ios::out | ios::in);
    if(!file){
        cout<<"File open failed!"<<endl;
    }else {
        cout<<"File open success!"<<endl;

        cout<<"Please enter the data to save into the file"<<endl;

        getline(cin, data);
        file << data;

        string d;
        file.seekp(0);
        if(file.is_open()) {
            while(1){
                d = file.get();
                cout<<d;
                if(file.eof()){
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        file.close();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Forexample: I wrote (c++ is an interesting language). after it is successfully written to the file, again I wrote (I like it) and after that the file content becomes (I like it interesting language )

Comment: if you want to open a file for overwriting its contents you need not mess around with `seekp` manually. What is the actual aim? Practicing with file pointers or overwritign the file contents?

Comment: `file.open("newFile.txt", ios::out | ios::in);` will fail unless the file exists. Is that what you want?

Comment: I was just practicing reading the file content after it is written by using the file pointers.

Comment: @TedLyngmo Yes the file exists. I know that

Comment: You may be looking for [`trunc`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/ios_base/openmode) for the open mode.

Comment: I not sure what is yuor problem. It seams to work as expected (ignoring some code errors): https://wandbox.org/permlink/PTXpGwAvL7WZfMYL it overrides old data written and keeps rest of old content.

Comment: Here is with more details: https://wandbox.org/permlink/wnyulanefZJUncxz

Comment: Please describe in clear way what is your expectation and actual result. Please provide: file content before run, user input, file content after run, file content after run you are expecting.

Comment: @MarekR My expectation is to completely overwrite old the file content after I run some new content, but it is not working. I am getting my old content messing with the new content.

Comment: https://wandbox.org/permlink/wnyulanefZJUncxz   here is the same. thanks for the help

Comment: `d = file.get(); cout<<d;` ... you need to check if `get()` returned `EOF` which will be hard since `d` is a `string` - why on earth is it a `string`?